# Algorithm to generate a binary matrix

Tags: algorithm, greedy, binary-matrix

Given two input arrays [R1, ..., Rn] and [C1, ..., Cn]. We want to create a binary matrix A (of size-nxn) such that the sum of elements in column i of A be Ci and the sum of elements in row j of A be Rj.

I tried to fill using greedy algorithm : fill 1's from left to right and decrement Ci's and do this for each row. But, it didn't work. (Also, then I tried to sort rows and columns in decreasing order but still didn't work)

Comment: Seems like there must be more to the problem definition. E.g. if `n` is 2 and `R1` is 3, then there's obviously no solution. And I have a feeling that there are plenty of unsolvable cases even if each R_i and C_i is less than `n`.

Comment: @user3386109 About your example, I think there exists such 2*2 matrix {{1,2}, {3, 4}}. R1 is 3 for the matrix.

Comment: @SauravSahu I wouldn't call that a ***binary*** matrix. I would expect a binary matrix to have only 0 or 1 as its entries.

Comment: This seems similar to solving certain types of [nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) puzzles, which is NP complete, although there are some tricks you can use.

Comment: @user3386109...Got it...my mistake..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be solved using Maximum Flows. A similar (harder version of this) problem is available on [LightOJ](http://lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1330), and my code for [reference](https://github.com/bk2dcradle/competitive/blob/master/LightOJ/Flows-Matching/Max-Flow-Min-Cut/1330.cc)

Here is the solution.

We will first create a bipartite graph. Let the number of rows be `no_rows` and number of columns be `no_cols`.

Now create `no_rows + no_cols` nodes. Arrange the first `no_rows` nodes in the left (which will form one "partite" of our bipartite graph). Lets number these nodes as `l1, l2, ..., lno_row`.

Similarly arrange the last `no_cols` nodes in the right (which will form the second "partite"). Lets number these as `r1, r2, ... , rno_cols`.

Now add edges between each `li` and `rj` for all `1 <= i <= no_rows` and
`1 <= j <= no_cols`, oriented from the left to the right, with a capacity of 1.

Now create a source(S) and a sink(T). Add edge of unit capacity oriented from source to each vertex on the left.

Similarly add edges of unit capacity oriented from each vertex on the right, to the sink.

Now just find the Maximum Flow in this graph. Now if there exists a flow between some `li` and some `rj`, that implies that the cell `(i, j)` will have 1, otherwise it will have 0.

Note: To ensure that there even exists such a binary matrix, make sure that each of the `(S, l)` edges and `(r, T)` edges are completely filled.

---

Edit: Here is an implementation of Dinic in C++ [ideone](http://ideone.com/cieUlL)

---

Edit 2: The capacity of the edge connecting the source to any `li` is `Ri` (where `R` is the given input array indicating row sums). Similarly the capacity of the edge connecting `ri` to sink `T` is `Ci` (where `C` is the array given in input indicating column sums)

Comment: Where and how do you add the values  [R1, ..., Rn] and [C1, ..., Cn] to the graph?

Comment: `Ri` are the capacity of the edge connecting `(S, li)` and `Ci` is the capacity of the edge connecting `(ri, T)`